# How to automatically copy my own arara rules in the correct folder after installing the new year's TeX Live distribution?

Tags: arara

I have a TeX Live distribution on Windows 10.

I use `arara` and I created a couple of `arara` rules by myself. I stored them in `C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\rules` together with the rules automatically provided by the distribution.

Now I have installed TeX Live 2017, and I had to copy my rules manually from the 2016 directory to `C:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\rules`.

Is there a way to do such a thing automatically or to add another folder of mine from which `arara` can search for my rules?

I'm asking this question because I realized I had to do that copy after getting the error:

```
ERROR Arara - Uh-oh, I could not find the '.......' rule in the search path. 
Could you take a look if the rule name is correct and if the rule is accessible through the search path?
```

Comment: you should probably have put them in `C:\texlive\texmf-local\scripts\arara\rules` then they would work any year

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think `arara` looks automatically in `texmf-local` for rules (not sure though.)

Comment: @AlanMunn hmm why doesn't it look in all the standard kpsesearch paths? all the standard search paths in `texmf.cnf` include `$TEXMFLOCAL` and the default setting for that is `texlive/texmf-local`

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `arara` does not look in `texmf-local` and the reason for that is: since the tool could be installed as standalone as well, I didn't want it to look in folders other than its own. I could make it automatically look in the local TeX tree, but I do believe it would be safer to include the full path in the configuration file. At the end of the day, it would behave the same. `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea ever to put local files into the `texmf-dist` folder of your distribution. That folder should be reserved for files installed by the distribution only.

`arara` looks in your home directory for a local configuration file, called `araraconfig.yaml` and you can then specify in that file any directory you like to put your rules.

My local `araraconfig.yaml` file looks like this:

```
!config
paths:
- /Users/alan/Dropbox/bin/arara
```

because I like to keep my `arara` rules inside my local `bin` folder (which I keep on Dropbox to make available to any of my computers) but you can make the path or the directory anything you like. You can also add any number of directories to the list.

So on Windows you can make a `araraconfig.yaml` and put it in your home folder. Then make a folder for your rules anywhere you like  and specify it in this file.

Comment: I must point out that in version 4.0 it will be possible to have a local `araraconfig.yaml` (i.e, inside your project) to map local rules (also inside the project). `:)`