# Compiling document with PerlTeX, then luaLaTeX - conditional \usepackage based on compilation tool

Tags: conditionals, arara, perl

Slightly connected to my previous question ([Output of PerlTex with current TeXlive on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507576/output-of-perltex-with-current-texlive-on-windows)), I have managed to generate .pdf files with PerlTeX (precisely, with option --latex=lualatex).

Next step to use this wonderful tool fully would be to be able to use it along with other tools I am already using and automate document creation.

As stated in PerlTeX documentation, page 8, I am compiling document with options:

```
--latex=lualatex --makesty
```

With that, file noperltex.sty is created. Then, after commenting out \usepackage{perltex} and adding \usepackage{noperltex}, the document can be compiled with only lualatex, not requiring perltex to compile. If I would need to compile document twice, but first with perltex, then with only lualatex, is there a way, how to do that conditionally?

If I may, it would be great to have solution involving arara, making the compilation also automatic.

I have already created a rule for arara to work with perltex (my first attempt, based on biber rule and rule for pythontex, so its very basic), in case of arara solution please consider next code:

```
perltex.yaml
```

```
!config
# perltex rule for arara
# author: Tomas Krulis based on Uwe Ziegenhagen
# requires arara 4.0+
identifier: perltex
name: perltex
commands:
- name: PerlTeX for advanced string manipulation
  command: >
    @{
        return getCommand('perltex', options, getBasename(file));
    }
arguments:
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
```

For testing, please consider next MWE:

```
% arara: perltex: { options: [ '--latex=lualatex', '--makesty' ] }
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[optional]{perltex}
%\usepackage{noperltex}

\ifperl

\perlnewcommand{\reversewords}[1]{join " ", reverse split " ", $_[0]}

\perlnewcommand{\hilbertmatrix}[1]{
my $result = '
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
';
$result .= '\begin{array}{' . 'c' x $_[0] . "}\n";
foreach $j (0 .. $_[0]-1) {
my @row;
foreach $i (0 .. $_[0]-1) {
push @row, ($i+$j) ? (sprintf '\frac{1}{%d}', $i+$j+1) : '1';
}
$result .= join (' & ', @row) . " \\\\\n";
}
$result .= '\end{array}
\]';
return $result;
}

\else

\newcommand{\reversewords}[1]{\color{red} #1}
\newcommand{\hilbertmatrix}[1]{\color{red} #1}

\fi

\begin{document}

\reversewords{Try doing this without Perl!}

\clearpage

\hilbertmatrix{20}

\end{document}
```

Please note, that document "works" as it is, but only thanks to conditional \ifperl, which simply sets any perlcommand argument to red text. The desired behavior is to compile with perltex and \usepackage{perltex}, then conditionally switch to \usepackage{noperltex}, when the document is compiled only with lualatex; so the \else part of \ifperl is not trigerred.

Thank very much for any insight in this, maybe peculiar, question.

EDIT: Updated MWE based on suggestion of Mrs. Fischer, to test with condition \IfFileExists. With arara, in step 2, of "only" luaLaTeX compilation, I am still getting "undefined control sequence" error with \perlnewcommand ; which leads me to think that still the \usepackage{noperltex} is not being picked up.

More interestingly, if I compile following MWE with PerlTeX only, I get the same error. I also have already noperltex.sty in project folder, with code, that (I think) doesnt involve definitions of \perlnewcommands in form, that could be processed by lualatex.

Looks like noperltex is created at start of perltex compilation, which prevents else part of \IfFileExists triggering. Is that the bug you encountered? Or is it intended?

EDITED MWE:

```
% arara: perltex: { options: [ '--latex=lualatex', '--makesty', '--nosafe' ] }
% arara: lualatex: { shell: yes }

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\IfFileExists{noperltex.sty}{%
\usepackage{noperltex}%
}%
{\usepackage[optional]{perltex}}

\perlnewcommand{\reversewords}[1]{join " ", reverse split " ", $_[0]}

\perlnewcommand{\hilbertmatrix}[1]{
my $result = '
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
';
$result .= '\begin{array}{' . 'c' x $_[0] . "}\n";
foreach $j (0 .. $_[0]-1) {
my @row;
foreach $i (0 .. $_[0]-1) {
push @row, ($i+$j) ? (sprintf '\frac{1}{%d}', $i+$j+1) : '1';
}
$result .= join (' & ', @row) . " \\\\\n";
}
$result .= '\end{array}
\]';
return $result;
}

\begin{document}

\reversewords{Try doing this without Perl!}

\clearpage

\hilbertmatrix{20}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the question is what is the condition you want to base the compilation on? The existence of noperltex.sty? Then what if the document changes and a newer noperltex.sty would be needed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your comment, Mrs. Fischer. The condition, on my part, is exactly the existence of noperltex.sty. It did not occured to me, could it be modified to condition \IfFileExists? (I try). The thought process it was: Incompatibilites and performance precautions. Being beginner (maybe even begginer) in LaTeX, I hit upon mistakes and incompatibilities. I thought, its safer to use PerlTeX only when necessary (to create noperltex.sty or modify it) and then go on only with luaLaTeX. Lastly, I think that PerlTeX is having slightly lower performance.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The \ifperl command was meant there as debug tool, to see, if \usepackage{noperltex} is executed or not.

Comment: testing if noperltex.sty exists should be easy both for arara (@paulocereda can do this) and in the document with \IfFileExists. Btw: I found a bug in perltex, with newer latex the noperltex errors, I already notified the author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Edited MWE based on your suggestion. Is it the bug you reported? If so, how can I monitor resolving the situation? (Is there a project GitHub site or anything like that?)

Comment: The bug is reported (by mail). Add `\makeatletter\let\plmac@tag\relax` after loading the (no)perltex package, but before the command as a work-around.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Did you meant the line after "{\usepackage[optional]{perltex}}"? If so, my situation still persists the same. Next I concluded that somewhere should be also \makeatother, putting it on next line or after the commands (before \begin{document}) did not led to resolving the situation.

Comment: The author has reported back. He will fix the bug soon.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much for notifying me, Mrs. Fischer. I will look forward to try it out. Tomas

Comment: you could sent me a mail then I will forward the new version to you and you can test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would happily do so, but actually, I dont know if it is possible to send here private message (I dare to say its not) so how can I send you my mail but not post it in the forum?

Comment: normally people are quite able to find my mail address if they want. Search a bit, e.g. look at my profile.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think I found it and sent short message as a contact link. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using `arara` (thank you!), how about the following approach:

1. Let's create a new rule named `writeconfig.yaml` which, as the name indicates, creates a configuration file based on the provided text:

   ```
   !config
   identifier: writeconfig
   name: WriteConfig
   authors:
   - Paulo Cereda
   commands:
   - name: Writing the configuration file
     command: >
       @{
           writeToFile(toFile(input), text + '\n', append);
           return true;
       }
   arguments:
   - identifier: input
     flag: >
       @{
           return parameters.input;
       }
     required: true
   - identifier: append
     flag: >
       @{
           return isTrue(parameters.append);
       }
     default: false
   - identifier: text
     flag: >
       @{
           return parameters.text;
       }
     required: true
   ```

   This rule takes at least two parameters, namely:

   - `input` (required): the name of our configuration file.
   - `text` (required): the text to be written.
   - `append` (optional): a flag indicating whether the content should be appended or overwritten (default behaviour is to overwrite the content, as we want to exploit this dea).

   > Prior to revision 2, `arara` 4.0 had a bug when handling boolean values as a return type for commands (as seen in issue [#128](https://github.com/cereda/arara/issues/128)). Make sure to update `arara` to at least revision 2 using your TeX distro manager, so the aforementioned rule will have the expected behaviour. You can check the revision by looking at the header when running the tool: `arara 4.0 (revision 2)`
2. Change your document and replace these lines:

   ```
   \usepackage[optional]{perltex} % for PerlTeX
   \usepackage{noperltex}         % for LuaLaTeX
   ```

   by this one:

   ```
   \input{config.cfg}
   ```
3. Now let's create new directives:

   ```
   % arara: writeconfig: { input: 'config.cfg', text: '\usepackage[optional]{perltex}' }
   % arara: perltex: { options: [ '--latex=lualatex', '--makesty' ] }
   % arara: writeconfig: { input: 'config.cfg', text: '\usepackage{noperltex}' }
   % arara: lualatex
   ```
4. Have fun:

```
 $ arara mwe.tex 
   __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
  / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
 | (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
  \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

 Processing 'mwe.tex' (size: 1003 bytes, last modified: 09/10/2019
 11:03:14), please wait.

 (WriteConfig) Writing the configuration file ............ SUCCESS
 (perltex) PerlTeX for advanced string manipulation ...... SUCCESS
 (WriteConfig) Writing the configuration file ............ SUCCESS
 (LuaLaTeX) LuaLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS

 Total: 2.60 seconds
```

Hope it helps! `:)`

**EDIT:** My suggestion is to keep both `writeconfig.yaml` and `perltex.yaml` inside your project directory. Then create a file named `arararc.yaml` (it's one of the four possible names for this file, I usually prefer this one) and add this to it:

```
!config
paths:
- '.'
```

It means to search the current project directory for rules first. Then try to run `arara` from this level.

Comment: I must be having trouble with adding WriteConfig (or the generated config.cfg) to path. I have writeconfig.yaml in current directory, for sure also in 2019/temf-dist (I know its not ideal).
My problem might be same as here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375841/how-to-automatically-copy-my-own-arara-rules-in-the-correct-folder-after-install
But I am having trouble adding current project directory to path in Windows 10. Could you help me with that, with say, the absolute current directory of the project is "C:\User\user\Documents\NewFolder" ?

Comment: @TomášKruliš I updated the answer and included a possible configuration at the end. Could you check if it works for you? `:)`

Comment: Still getting same error message (which I dont understand):

The system command execution has failed due to an IO error. Are
you sure the provided system command exists in your path? It
might be a good idea to check the path and see if the command is
available. There are more details available on this exception:

DETAILS ---------------------------------------------------------
Could not execute [true].

Total: 0.12 seconds
C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 2:
java.exe -jar c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\arara.jar mwe

Comment: @TomášKruliš wait a minute! That's... odd... Let me check something here really quick and I will report back in a minute.

Comment: @TomášKruliš: something very odd is going on. I provided a patch to the `writeconfig.yaml` rule, could you update it and try again, please?

Comment: I tryed newest version, on my side arara doesnt display message "writing config file," eventhough it is written (minor issue). After compilation, .pdf is produced only with red text - mean that \ifperl \else part is triggered, as if there was no \usepackage{noperltex}, eventhough ii is generated.
Concluding, the second part of invoking \package{noperltex} when processing with lualatex is not working.

Comment: @TomášKruliš hold on, there's a lot of information going on... `:)` I will try to tidy up something soon..

Comment: OK, sure, thank you very much for your help Mr. Cereda. Frankly, you are doing all the hard work here. If there would be any clarification required (eventhough I think most should be written here or in mentioned perltex documentation, specifically at page 8), just let me know.
Currently I am visiting an conference meeting, so my response might be (a little) slower, but I try my best running the elevator to PC as soon as I notice.

Comment: @TomášKruliš Oh it's my pleasure and honour to help you! Actually, let me explain what's going on: you seem to have identified a potential bug in the underlying expression language used by `arara`. In Linux and MacOS, I get the correct workflow, but when I shift my execution to Windows, things seems to inexplicably fail! As a workaround for `writeconfig`, I forced a "dummy" command to be executed when in Windows (it's a mere `cd .` that does absolutely nothing, but makes the tool happy). (to be continued)

Comment: @TomášKruliš (continued) Now, could you update `writeconfig.yaml` yet again and try the new workflow? Also, could you take a look if `config.cfg` is generated, and also if its contents correspond to the correct context? Try the first two directives and see if PerlTeX generates the correct files. Then try the two last directives. I think things should be in place now. The reason for the lack of generation might be because `arara` halted after the `writeconfig` error.

Comment: After patch, with first 2 directives active, everything works as expected, config file is generated and .pdf is created with expected content.
While trying the third and fourth directives (together), undesired red text is generated, stating that \ifperl goes again through the \else code. But, in config.cfg is the desired text: \usepackage{noperltex}.
If I use all 4 directives at once, output is again the undesired one.
Could this be a problem of somehow \ifperl being processed sooner than \input?

Comment: @TomášKruliš I don't think so because `\ifperl` seems be defined in `noperltex`. If it were the case, the compilation would fail. I am sorry I cannot provide any pointers to you on this regard. Perhaps you should try invoking `lualatex` with shell escape enabled? If so, try `lualatex: { shell: yes }` in the `arara` directive, might be worth a shot...

Comment: I tryed to lift all security lifts I know of ( mentioned shell: yes option, but also perltex --nosafe option followed by --shell-escape lualatex option, as a driving engine behind perltex ) and none of it led to desired \package{noperltex} execution.
Even if I have disabled the \ifperl command completely (hoping somewhere will be resume point, where \usepackage{noperltex} would prevail, I got failed compilation attempt of lualatex.
Hopefully I never end up in situation, where I would need to compile document with perltex more then once, if perltex would be anywhere else than at start.

Comment: That would mean to go back into "pre-arara" times and I dont want that.
Thank you very much for your help Mr. Cereda, it was wonderfull experience to communicate with you.
Regards, Tomas

Comment: @TomášKruliš sorry to hear about your bad experience. LuaLaTeX with shell escape works for me and generates the document accordingly (even with method invocation). I hope to understand the scenario better in the future, so I can provide better assistance to you...